# Permanent write, execute, and read permissions for "other" users on Samba

Tags: server, permissions, files, samba, sharing

I am rather new to Linux and Ubuntu,

I have set up a file sharing samba server with a shared folder in my "home" directory called "s2program". Our computers run a simple custom made program that regularly gets updated. The updates are done via a windows machine and are installed on the samba server in the "s2program" folder.

The problem arises when the update program deletes all the subfolders in the "s2program" folder and then recreates the sub folders and reinstalls all the files, including the new files that have been updated" however when these new sub folders are created ubuntu or samba I'm not sure which does not allow anything to be written to these sub-folders. When I check the samba share information in nautilus' properties it does not allow me to change the permissions for the "enclosed folders and files" for "other" users.

I have tried using the terminal command  `sudo chmod 777 foldername` but once the update program has deleted the sub folders and recreates them I often need to re-enter the above terminal command. This has the effect that the updates are being terminated.

Please can someone shed some insight into my problem.
I would like to avoid setting up user groups and have every workstation log in I would prefer all users "others" to be able to log in as others and have full access. Or must I create a specific user group?

Comment: what is the program written in, C? shell? bash? because if its bash or shell you can add the command to the program :)

Comment: I have no idea what the program is written in and unfortunately it cannot be rewritten at this time. :(

Comment: @vantixs What permissions would you want to set for all subfolders and files? Do you want `777` (This is not recommended)?